# C++ использование объекта абстрактного типа класса не допускается

Tags: c++, ооп, полиморфизм, виртуальная-функция

Есть базовый класс Shape

```
class Shape{
public:
    virtual void print() = 0;
    virtual double area() = 0;
    virtual double volume() = 0;
};
```

Унаследованный TwoDShpape

```
class TwoDShape : public Shape{
public:
    virtual void print() = 0;
    virtual double area()=0;
};
```

Унаследованный Circle

```
class circle : public TwoDShape {
    int radius;
public:
    void print() {
        cout << "It's a circe. Radius: " << radius << endl;
    }

    circle(int _radius) : radius(_radius) {}

    double area() {
        return 3.14 * radius * radius;
    }
};
```

Но при создании объекта в main возникает ошибка Е0322 использование объекта абстрактного типа класса circle не допускается.

Comment: Вам необходимо реализовать метод `volume`

Comment: В пояснении к ошибке же указывается, причина `message : 'double Shape::volume(void)': is abstract`

Comment: покажите `main`, тогда станет гораздо понятнее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конкретный класс не должен иметь ни одной абстрактной функции-члена, т.е. должен переопределять их все.

`print` и `area` вы переопрделили, а `volume` остался абстрактным, а значит, ваш `Circle` - тоже абстрактный, и работать с ним непосредственно нельзя.